How do you render code in two columns in ASCIIDOC?
In the ASCIDOC, I'd like to render the [source] code block in one row of two-column table. How can I do it?

I found the syntax that worked for me.
.Table title
[options="header"]
|=======
| Column 1 | Column 2

a|
[source]
----
echo "Hello World A"
----
a|
[source]
----
echo "Hello World B"
----
|=======

The above code should render this table.

